# SATA disk resets every 10 seconds

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I have a bizarre issue which I simply cannot find any info on.

I have a SATA disk that has no SMART errors, in fact I now have 2 identical with no errors. Whenever I perform disk work it resets every 5 seconds or so, it makes a distinct click and data transfer drops to 0 for a moment.

**Backstory**:

Started happening about 6 months intermittently. I changed the cables and changed the SATA slots. I bought a second drive (same make and size) and it did the same. I tested the drives in a different PC and they worked fine.

I concluded the SATA controller on the motherboard had gone south despite my SSD still working fine. I bought a PCI-E SATA expander and plugged in the now 2 HDs and they worked fine. Quite pleased with myself!

Now, one of the drives has developed the original issue whilst the other remains working fine.

PC is Windows 10, LGA 1150, i7-4770k,
the disks are Seagate Barracuda 1tb, motherboard is Gigabyte Z87-HD3.

What is causing this? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Just sounds like bad drives. Your description would seem to eliminate that possibly. But SMART will not always detect issues. Run a full surface scan on the drives. Use seatools, hddscan, or my personal favorite HDD regenerator.

Answer (score 1):

A bad disk does not need to report SMART errors.

You need to confirm the behavior is specific to the disk itself. Do this by trying it in another computer. This controls for the variables of the disk controller, data cable, power supply and connector and operating system.

While connected to a different system run the manufacturer's diagnostics software. It can help identify or confirm a diagnosis of a failing drive. I use the [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) for this because it includes manufacturer-specific diagnostic software from all of the major disk manufacturers.

Even if the disk diagnostics report nothing wrong, if the abnormal behavior follows the drive, it is defective and should be handled accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have indeed used SeaTools to test the drive and all test pass without error. The drive works fine in different PC.

Comment: Then try to systematically eliminate components that could be to blame (which you've already begun by trying different cables and ports). Try a different power supply. Try running a different OS (eg a live USB copy of Ubuntu).

Comment: Yeah, a new PSU is next on the list. I did swap over the power cables as well. I have moved everything off that drive now so the issue is not happening. I will wait to see if it starts on the second drive. I have run loads of diagnostic including Intel CPU and RAM tests, no errors, no errors anywhere, accept both drives kept reseting, before I got the PCI-E SATA card. Now it has happened again but only on 1 drive, no errors. PSU is next.

Comment: Do try another OS too. This will help rule out controller drivers and OS-specific behaviors. Do keep in mind bad drives don't always trigger diagnostic errors. Drives that act bad are bad, no matter what diagnostics say.

Comment: I heat what you say but the second drive was to rule out a faulty drive and when I first plugged it in it show the same issue brand new and then I put them both into a different PC and they both worked fine. I am not convinced it is a drive issue.

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar BUT it was a long time ago .. could be a (not enough) power issue or maybe power settings ... are your drives set to sleep ?? If i remember rightly my problem was with wd geeen drives and they had aggresive head parking routines, so they would "park" the heads after every access.. I found a program that would keep alive the drives. I would do a disk test (many hours) and email the mfr detailing your problem, they are the experts after all. OH , and maybe try freezing your drives and ++defrosting++ , weird .. but they're sealed . If they're old (5years) then replace. I did run WD blacks daily for seven years + no problems...

Comment: Freeze and defrost? Ugh.... the drives are NOT sealed.